# Batch processing: read image files, then write multidimensional numpy array to HDFS

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdfs, batch-processing

I am trying to iteratively load a batch of images from a folder, process, then store the results of the batch to an hdf file. What's the best practice for batch reading images/files, and batch storing a resulting multi-dimensional array?

## First Part

I start with a csv list of file names:

```
file_list = [''.join(x) + '.png' for x in permutations('abcde')][:100]
```

Say for example I want to process 5 images at a time.

I currently grab 5 file names from the list, create an empty array to hold 5 images, then read each image one at a time to yield a batch.

```
 def load_images(file_list):
     for i in range(0, 100, 5):
          files_list = file_list[i, i + 5]
          image_list = np.zeros(shape=(5, 50, 50, 3))

          for idx, file in enumerate(files_list):
              loaded_img = np.random.random((50, 50, 3))  # misc.imread(file) 
              image_list[idx] = loaded_img
          yield image_list, files_list
```

**Question 1:** Is there a way to eliminate the second for loop? Can I batch read in the images, or is the method above (one at a time) best practice?

## Second Part:

After loading the images I do some processing on them. This results in a different size array

```
def process_images(image_batch):
    result = image_batch[:, 5, 4, 3]  # a novel down-sampling algorithm
    return result
```

Now, I want to store the batch of images with their original file names.

```
def store_images(data, file_names):
    with pd.HDFstore('output.h5') as hdf:
        pass
```

**Question 2:** What is the best way to store a batch of multidimensional numpy arrays, while still referencing them with a key (such as the original file name)?

I would like to explore using .h5 files, so if anyone knows how to batch process data to an .h5 and has advice on this, it would be most appreciated. Alternatively I think there is a way to save the numpy arrays as just .npy files to a folder, but I was having trouble with this and still wouldn't know how to do it other than one sample at a time (versus one batch at a time)

Comment: did you figure this out?